# Connect to MS-Access in JBoss

Tags: ms-access, jboss, connection

I'm develpoing an application under JBoss-As 7. In the application, I need to generate a MS-Access file which includes some data. To do that I used an already created MS-Access file and use Jdbc-Odbc Brdige to connect and insert data. The problem is that I can not connect to in the application-server environment. It throws NoClassDefFoundError: sun/jdbc/odbc/JdbcOdbcDriver. (JBoss under windows 7).
Can someone has idea to move my application to linux and connect to MS-Access file in Linux.

Best

Comment: Did you check that your classpath contains the rt.jar in class path? By default it would get shipped with JDK. If not then you need copy rt.jar for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

For my problem, jackcess worked fine. Please read and use it (jackcess.sourceforge.net).